# having trouble getting average color (red, green, blue) from list of lists using zip()

Tags: python, average

I have an image (list of lists) and I want to return the average color of that entire image.
I tried using zip() to slice the image into 3 parts by red, green, blue but when I run the code:

```
def average(image):
    """Returns the average color of the pixels in the image"""
    red = []
    green = []
    blue = []
    for r, g, b in zip(image):
        red.append(r), green.append(g), blue.append(b)
    average_color = (sum(red) / len(red)), (sum(green) / len(green)), \
                    (sum(blue) / (len(blue)))
    return average_color
```

It says:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1).
```

I'm not sure what is wrong, did `zip()` make only 1 slice?

Comment: Is `image` a sequence of `(red, green, blue)` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `image` is a sequence of tuples with `(r, g, b)` values, you need to apply the whole sequence as separate arguments with `*args`. This produces 3 new lists, with colour bands separated for you:

```
def average(image):
    red, green, blue = zip(*image)
    return (
        sum(red) / len(red),
        sum(green) / len(green), 
        sum(blue) / (len(blue))
```

`zip()` combines values from one or more iterables; you gave it just the one iterable, so you'll just get the same values back:

```
>>> sample = [('foo', 'bar', 'baz'), ('spam', 'ham', 'eggs')]
>>> next(zip(sample))
('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

But if you use `*args` you apply each of the contained elements in the sequence as a *separate* argument, as if you called `zip()` with `zip(args[0], args[0], ..., args[n])`, effectively giving you the transposed columns of the rows:

```
>>> next(zip(*sample))
('foo', 'spam')
```

where `'foo'` and `'spam'` are the first values of the two tuples in `sample`.